# Problems forwarding messages on Openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe, converse.js

I'm sending the following XML to Openfire, hoping that it forwards the message for me, or just returns me something telling me where I'm wrong:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" rid="2294433114" sid="69764wvapw">
   <message xmlns="jabber:client" to="dumb2@mydomain" from="alex3@mydomain/converse.js-123790907" type="chat" id="0d7818c0-5270-417e-b638-234828cb9f99">
      <body>af</body>
      <forwarded xlmns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
         <delay xmns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="1458142619552" />
         <message from="dumb3@mydomain" to="felipe3@mydomain" type="chat">
            <body>af</body>
         </message>
      </forwarded>
   </message>
</body>
```

But the server only returns me:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="2294433114"/>
```

Messages and users do exist.

What's wrong?